# laravel 8 I want to access method from all the controller like app controller before_filter() in cakephp . How I can do that in laravel8?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel . I worked on cakephp before.. I used app controller on cakephp to define global access methods. How and Where I define global access method in Laravel ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do... As in cakePHP you extend a controller. You CAN put methods in App\Http\Controllers\Controller. But in Laravel you also have (for example) Helpers and Middleware.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Composer Autoloader for this.  It is best to create your methods under App / Helper / helpers.php.  Then you have to register the file in Composer.  You do that in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
     "files": [
         "app / helpers.php"
     ],
     "classmap": [
         "database / seeds",
         "database / factories"
     ],
     "psr-4": {
         "App \\": "app /"
     }
 },
```

Now all you have to do is execute the following command.  For Composer to register the new autoload:

```
composer dump-autoload
```